# Can you pressurize a vessel to ambient pressure if the outside pressure is 0 psi?

Tags: pressure

let's say we have a vessel that is open to the atmosphere and is located at an altitude where the atmospheric pressure is about 0 psi. Then, we hook up a pressure pump and attempt to bring the pressure of the vessel back up to sea-level pressure. Is this possible or not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the ISS is up where the atmosphere is about zero psi, and it is pressurized. But, not from what little ambient there is. In theory one might (slowly) collect residual gas, but not quickly...

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Physics SE!

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No! The vessel is open to the surrounding atmosphere so that it will always be in equilibrium with it. However, if the opening is very small and the supply of high pressure gas of a high enough volume, then the pressure in the vessel would rise. This is analogous to a car tyre having a blowout or a slow puncture.

Comment: Okay so if the vessel was originally open to the atmosphere, then sealed and connected to a pressure pump which only takes air from the atmosphere (o psi) to pump into the vessel, it could be brought back to ambient pressure? or is a separate gas of higher pressure required? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Dave, and welcome to Physics SE! Good first answer! It would be more correct to say "it will always *tend* to be in equilibrium."

Comment: @W.Vacek you would need *some* air for the pump to work!

Comment: Andrea. Thanks. You are correct, it would always tend to equilibrium.

Comment: If the atmospheric pressure was zero, then even a pump with an external power source

Comment: Sorry hit send by mistake! You seem to be confusing ambient and zero psi. Perhaps you mean  0psig not 0psi. The pump, with an external power source, can pump gas into a vessel increasing the pressure of the gas in the vessel . However, at 0psi, there is no gas to pump!